# How to implement hierarchical optional sections?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to implement, using javascript and jquery (1.9.1), the concept of optional sections.

Basically, I have a `checkbox` that enable or disable a whole section (which is a `div`).

Here I have a working code :

```
<div class="optional">
    <span class="optional-activator"> 
        <input type="checkbox" ></input>
    </span>

    <div class="optional-section">
        <input type="text" value="sometext" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and a script :

```
$(function () {
    $(".optional").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var activator = $this.find(".optional-activator :input");
        var section = $this.find(".optional-section");

        var sectionStateUpdate = function () {
            if (activator.prop('checked')) {
                section.find(":input").prop("disabled", false);
                section.removeClass("inactive");
            } else {
                section.find(":input").prop("disabled", true);
                section.addClass("inactive");
            }
        };
        activator.change(sectionStateUpdate);
        sectionStateUpdate();                       
    });
});
```

This is working as expected.

However, this code does not support nested optional sections. When the higher optional section is enabled, the whole `input` descendant are also enabled, not regarding the possible presence in a sub section.

For example, this snippet won't work as expected :

```
<div class="optional"> 
    <span class="optional-activator"> 
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </span>

    <div class="optional-section">
        <input type="text" value="sometext2" />
        <div class="optional"> 
            <span class="optional-activator"> 
                <input type="checkbox" />
            </span>

            <div class="optional-section">
                <input type="text" value="sometext3" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I update my code to support the nesting?

To be more precise, the rules are :

- if an optional section is disabled, all input controls in the section are disabled, even if it is in an nested optional section
- if an optional section is enable, all direct input controls are enabled too, but the nested optional section must reflect their own activator

I wrote these snippets into a [jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/f5kmh/3/) to illustrate my behavior.

Comment: downvote? please justify, if I can improve my question

Answer (score 0):

The solution is visible [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f5kmh/12/).

Basically, the idea was to change the behavior. Now there is a method that refreshes the whole page sections availability.

And when any of the checkbox is changed, the whole sections are refreshed, instead of refreshing only the selected section.

My javascript is then :

```
$(function () {
    var refresh = function () {
        $(".optional").each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var activator = $this.find(".optional-activator :input");
            var section = $this.find(".optional-section");

            if (activator.prop('checked')) {
                section.find(":input").filter(":not(.optional-section)").prop("disabled", false);
                section.removeClass("inactive");
            } else {
                section.find(":input").prop("disabled", true);
                section.addClass("inactive");
            }
        });
    };
    $(".optional-activator :input").change(refresh);
    refresh();
});
```

The tricky part was to exclude nested sections when activating a top section (see the usage of `.filter`)